# Angular - How to port React interfaces into @Input decorator

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript

Here's what I have in React (stripped away some code) that I'm trying to port to Angular:

```
interface IProps {
    xs: any;
    height: string;
    stat: Stat;
    statSchema: StatSchema;
    team?: Team;
    activePlayers?: Player[];
    subStatTitle?: string;
    requestMatchAction: (mar: MatchActionRequest) => void;
}

interface IState {
    selectedSubStatId?: string;
    selectSubStatOpen: boolean;
    selectPlayerOpen: boolean;
    success: boolean;
}

class BasicStatControl extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
    public state: IState = {
        selectSubStatOpen: false,
        selectPlayerOpen: false,
        success: true
    };
```

What I am trying to do is create a scoring interface in Angular. I've created a React version, but I need to port it to Angular (I'm new to Angular btw). End goal is to have two buttons (Field Goal Made / Field Goal Attempted) that opens a dialog/modal upon button click. The dialog/modal will either be a list of Players or SubStat (specify that the 2 pt field goal was a layup, dunk, jumpshot for example).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that the implementation of React's interface IProps is equivalent to Angular's @Input decorator. I took a stab at it, and came up with this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nvo-basic-stat-control',
  templateUrl: './basic-stat-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basic-stat-control.component.css']
})
export class BasicStatControlComponent {
  @Input() height: string;
  @Input() stat: Stat;
  @Input() statSchema: StatSchema;
  @Input() team?: Team;
  @Input() activePlayers?: Player[];
  @Input() subStatTitle?: string;
  @Output() requestMatchAction = new EventEmitter();

  @Input() selectedSubStatId?: string;
  @Input() selectSubStatOpen: boolean;
  @Input() selectPlayerOpen: boolean;
  @Input() success: boolean;
  constructor() {}
}
```

I don't think this is the correct implementation as I've just written all of the properties, but there's no way to distinguish the structure (In the React app, a specific set of properties are defined/tied to IProps and IState respectively). What is the correct way to go about this?

Also, what is the Angular equivalent of React's this.props? Appreciate any guidance/direction. Thanks!

Comment: Input is appropriate if you want to pass these values in via HTML attributes. How do you actually want to create and populate this component? It appears to be doing a *lot* (possibly too much.)

Comment: I would most likely use the IProps interface much like you described as passing values in (such as team via HTML/interpolation). However, a property like activePlayers would be used in my child component/player dialog where I list the entire roster + the players that are on the court (activePlayers) I need to ensure that the requestMatchAction object is passed to the parent hence the @Output. IState is important as that is what controls whether the SubStat/Players modal/dialog is open or not

Comment: So why not pass in interface instances/objects into the `@Input`s?

Comment: Like this?                                                                                                                     @Input() props: { height: string; stat: Stat; statSchema: StatSchema; team?: Team; activePlayers?: Player[]; subStatTitle?: string;}                                                   @Output() requestMatchAction = new EventEmitter();